# mysql query for the following tables

Tags: mysql

How to make one Mysql query for the following tables to find email field in following condition,

but the conditions are,
1. advisorid from comp table = 1 and receiverid from trance table = 1 and
2. when dates from both table are in between '2012-02-01' and '2012-02-30'.

please help,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know which data(columns) you need but, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM comp c, trance t WHERE c.advisorid = 1 
AND t.receiverid = 1 
AND c.changedate BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-02-30'
AND t.date BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-02-30'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [left](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function to get the proper number in receiverid from trance table.

```
select c.email 
from comp c INNER JOIN trance t
on c.id = t.id
where (c.advisorid = 1 and left(t.receiverid,1) = 1) 
and (c.changedate between '2012-02-30' and '2012-02-01')
and (t.date between '2012-02-30' and '2012-02-01');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.email AS EMAIL
FROM trance t, comp c
WHERE  c.advisorid = 1 
   AND t.receiverid = 1 
   AND c.changedate BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-02-30'
   AND t.date BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-02-30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this query..


select * from comp as a INNER JOIN trance as b ON a.id=b.id WHERE a.advisorid=1 AND b.receiverid=1 AND (a.changedate >='2012-02-01' and a.changedate <= '2012-02-30') AND (b.date >='2012-02-01' and b.date'<='2012-02-30')
```